# How to add utility functions to an interface

Tags: vb.net

I'm collecting data items from 5 different sources, for each source I have a data item class that deals with the quirks of that particular source. For example purposes, lets have these two:

```
Public Class wild_banana
    Implements banana
    Public ReadOnly Property weight As Single Implements banana.weight
    Public ReadOnly Property volume As Single Implements banana.volume

    Public Sub New(wild_path As String)
        Dim bytes = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(wild_path)
        _weight = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0)
        _volume = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 4)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class domestic_banana
    Implements banana
    Public ReadOnly Property weight As Single Implements banana.weight
    Public ReadOnly Property volume As Single Implements banana.volume

    Public Sub New(weight As Single, volume As Single)
        Me._weight = weight
        Me._volume = volume
    End Sub
End Class
```

(in this example, there isn't really a need for 2 different banana classes as it could easily be solved with a constructor overload but lets pretend there is a good reason)

All of the 5 item classes implement a common interface that I use for everything else past the data collection stage. Example:

```
Public Interface banana
    ReadOnly Property weight As Single
    ReadOnly Property volume As Single
End Interface
```

For convenience sake, I'd like to add some utility functions that strictly depend on the properties available to the interface. Lets say I want the density of the banana, it would be perfect if I could do it like this:

```
Public Interface banana
    ReadOnly Property weight As Single
    ReadOnly Property volume As Single
    Function get_density() As Single
        Return weight / volume
    End Function
End Interface
```

But I cannot. Neither can I inherit an interface, the only remaining option would be to create a new class that holds a banana field, duplicates the banana interface by just having a bunch of pass through properties and has a banana widening operator... a lot of work and increased maintenance, no thanks.

Is there anything else that I'm missing? Aside from resorting to functional programming, how can I add utility functions to my interface without duplicating the implementation 5 times?

Comment: Instead of using an Interface, how about having a a base `banana` class and having `wild_banana` and `domestic_banana` inherit from the base class.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is probably easier using class inheritance.

You could have a base class called `banana` that includes you `weight` and `volume` properties (make the property setters Protected if you only want derived classes to be able to change the property). The base class can also include your utility functions (such as `density`).

Now create classes that inherit from `banana` such as `wild_banana` and `domestic_banana` that contain the code unique to these special classes.

For example.

```
Public Class banana
    Dim _weight, _volume As Single

    Public Property weight As Single
        Get
            Return _weight
        End Get
        Protected Set(value As Single)
            _weight = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property volume As Single
        Get
            Return _volume
        End Get
        Protected Set(value As Single)
            _volume = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Function get_density() As Single
        Return weight / volume
    End Function
End Class

Public Class wild_banana
    Inherits banana

    Public Sub New(wild_path As String)
        Dim bytes = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(wild_path)

        Me.weight = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0)
        Me.volume = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 4)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class domestic_banana
    Inherits banana

    Public Sub New(weight As Single, volume As Single)
        Me.weight = weight
        Me.volume = volume
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is a little more complicated than you wanted, because the weight and volume properties are now inherited they can't be declared as ReadOnly in a single statement auto-implemented property (e.g. `Public ReadOnly Property weight As Single`). This is because you wouldn't be able to change them from the child classes' constructors (`Sub New`). However, if you don't mind the properties being read/write, you could save some statements in the base class (e.g. `Public Property weight As Single`)

Comment: Nice answer. I clarified the reason that you can't use `ReadOnly` properties in the base class. If this wasn't what you meant or if you are unsatisfied with the edit feel free to change it again or rollback.

Comment: @user81993 : If you also don't want to be able to create an instance of the `banana` class (like you can't create an instance of an interface), you can declare it as `Public MustInherit Class banana`.